# How to pull twitter feed in content type?

Tags: feeds, social-network

I need to create content type(twitter content ) where i can pull twitter feeds so that i can use that content type for entity reference and print the twitter feeds.

Can any one please help or assist me how pull twitter feeds in custom content type?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have twitter block module in drupal 7 , but you want content type for this make node--twitterfeed.tpl.php  template  and put your api script like this

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/myapp" data-widget-id="123456789">Tweets by @InstaSnapShop</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

also check https://www.drupal.org/project/twitter_block